# Silverlight: Calling properties on static resources

Tags: silverlight, xaml

This is the XAML I want to write:

```
Background="{Binding Blah.Count, FallbackValue={StaticResource CountToColorConverter.FallbackBrush}, Converter={StaticResource CountToColorConverter}}">
```

IS there a way to express this in Silverlight XAML?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anyway that I can find.  You will need to stor the FallbackBrush as a separate resource rather than trying to expose it as a property of the converter.  Your binding becomes:-

```
Background="{Binding Blah.Count, FallbackValue={StaticResource FallbackBrush}, Converter={StaticResource CountToColorConverter}}">
```

Where somewhere there is something like:-

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FallbackBrush">Red</SolidColorBrush>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option for me. Is there a way to initialize the FallbackBrush with a property on another resource?

Comment: Or maybe use a binding expression where the data source is a resource?

Comment: @Jonathan: Nope and Nope. Why is not an option?